# How to change port number when hosting minio server?

Tags: port, config, host, endpoint, minio

I am currently working on a project where I am attempting to use MinIO with a data moving program developed by my company. This broker software only allows for devices using port 80 to successfully complete a job; however, any avid user of MinIO knows that MinIO hosts on port 9000. So my question is, is there a way to change the port on which the MinIO server is hosted? I've tried looking through the config.json file to find an address variable to assign a port number to but each of the address variables I attempted to change had no effect on the endpoint port number. For reference, I am hosting MinIO on a windows 10 virtual machine during the test phase of the project and will be moving it onto a dedicated server (also windows 10) upon successful completion of testing.

Answer (score 11):

Add `--address :80` when you start your minio.
You can refer to this: https://docs.min.io/docs/multi-tenant-minio-deployment-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

When you start the minio server use the following command…

minio server start --address :[port you want to use]

for example…

minio server start --address :8000

Comment: What does this add to s123unny's 2020 answer?